# Regular expression negative lookbehind

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to have a matching regexp pattern that matches all the addresses that end in 4 or more digits, but not coming after `'APT'`, `'BOX'`, `'APT '`, or `'BOX '`.
So it should match the following cases:

```
HITME 1234
HITME 12345
HITME1234
```

but not the following cases:

```
BOX 1234
BOX 12345
BOX4044
APT 1234
APT 12345
NONHIT123
NONHIT 123
```

I have made this one

```
(?<!(APT |BOX ))([0-9]{4,})$
```

but it does not work right. Somehow still matches the no-no cases.

Comment: try `(?<!APT|BOX|APT |BOX )([0-9]{4,})`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This still matches PO BOX 123456

Comment: What do you mean "still matches the no no cases"? Running this on https://regex101.com/ doesn't match "NONHIT123"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just mean I don't want it match any of the second group of texts provided,

Comment: Ah, these are on separate lines. You can take advantage of that: `^(?!APT|BOX).*?([0-9]{4,})$`

Comment: Is `PO BOX 1234` valid? Your accepted solution will match it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** use `^(?!APT|BOX).*?([0-9]{4,})$`

---

Your regex `(?<!(APT |BOX ))([0-9]{4,})$` incorrectly matches:

- `BOX 12345` on `2345` because it is not preceded by `APT`  or `BOX` . Instead, it is preceded by `BOX 1`
- `BOX4044` on `4044` because it is not preceded by `APT`  or `BOX` . Instead, it is preceded by `BOX`
- `APT 12345` on `2345` for a similar reason.

The regex you're looking for is `^(?!APT|BOX).*?([0-9]{4,})$`, which is broken down like so:

- `^(?!APT|BOX)` - the beginning of the string cannot be followed by `APT` or `BOX`
- `.*?` - a bunch of garbage in the middle of the string, taking as few characters as possible (i.e. `HITME`  in your test cases)
- `([0-9]{4,})$` - the matched digits at the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

You can not add `APT` and `BOX` to the same alternation in the lookbehind assertion because they have to be of the same length.

Also **note** that your pattern would only match digits.

You can add another lookbehind with the other 2 alternatives, and assert that the match starts at a position that does not have a digit directly to the left.

We can not use a word boundary `\b` before matching the digits as you expect a match for `HITME1234`

```
(?<!\bAPT |\bBOX )(?<!\bAPT|\bBOX)(?<!\d)[0-9]{4,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9iMCkf/1)

Depending on the allowed characters before the last digits, you could make use of a negative lookahead and word boundaries to get the whole match and still get a match for `BOXA 1234`

The pattern asserts that from the start of the string there is not BOX or APT followed by optional spaces followed by a digit:

```
^(?!(?:BOX|APT)(?=[^\S\n]*\d))\w+[^\S\n]*\d{4,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V8StWG/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to match the following regular expression.

```
^(?:(?:BOX|APT) *\d{4,}|\D*\d{,3}|\D*(\d{4,}))$
```

Capture group 1 will contain the digits at the end of the string if the string conforms to the requirements.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pP2lhg/1)

The expression is an alternation with the three parts. The first two match, but do not capture, strings that are not valid. The third matches *and captures* the digits in a valid string. So the idea is to pay attention only to matches that capture a substring as well. (This is not my crazy invention; it's a well-worn technique that has been used since the Mesozoic Era.)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^                     # match the beginning of the string
(?:                   # begin a non-capture group
  (?:BOX|APT) *\d{4,} # match 'BOX' or 'APT' followed by 4 or more spaces
                      # followed by 4 or more spaces
|                     # or
  \D*\d{,3}           # match 0 or more non-digits, followed by 0 to 3 digits
|                     # or
  \D*                 # match 0 or more non-digits
  (                   # begin capture group 1
    \d{4,}            # match 4 or more digits
  )                   # end capture group 1
)                     # end non-capture group
$                     # match end of string
```

Note all variable-length matches ( `*`, `\D*`, `\d{4,}` and `\d{,3}`) are *greedy*, meaning as many characters as possible are to be matched.

Comment: That's a nice creative solution :-)

Comment: @The, thanks. btw, I've always wondered what it looks like from inside a black hole. Now that you've been fully enveloped by XTE J1118+490 (aka "SO") I thought you could tell me what it looks like (aside from having seen Elvis while you were being devoured, as you reported earlier). Also, could you ask the driver to hover over the Kremlin and then Mar-A-Lago?

Comment: It's great out here, with all that gravity it is a bit hard to type though. I asked the driver, but he first wants to make the black hole great again.

Answer (score -1):

```
/(?<!(APT.+|BOX(.+)?))([0-9]{4,})$/gm
```

Comment: In Python we cannot use variable-length lookbehinds (also they're not very performant anyway).

Comment: Best to always test (at regex101.com, for example).

Comment: @Gaberocksall, you will agree, however, that when supported by the regex engine, variable-length lookbehinds are sometimes the only option available. Incidentally, I would be grateful if you would refrain from using the p-word in my presence, as seeing it causes me to break out in hives.

Comment: Almost nothing is ever "the only option available", and it's certainly not the case for this question (see my answer). If the word "Python" impacts you so violently, please stay away from Python questions for your own health and that of the community.